# Where is efi files after installation without EPS partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, grub-efi

I have it to fast and the default ubuntu-22.04.1-server installed.
Booting is good. I've read before that ESP is required as standard. Now, i will try to found efi's files...

**Does anyone have any ideas about this?**

```
sda                         8:0    0    20G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0   1.8G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  18.2G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  18.2G  0 lvm  /

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: UUID="29ab3102" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="c9bcbedc" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="33ae1d8b"
/dev/sda3: UUID="OfZPJx" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="6495663a"
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="9a027567"

Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
    Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: C2AF092F-0A19-422B-8875-56219F49F593
    
    Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
    /dev/sda1     2048     4095     2048    1M BIOS boot
    /dev/sda2     4096  3719167  3715072  1.8G Linux filesystem  
    /dev/sda3  3719168 41940991 38221824 18.2G Linux filesystem  

/boot
├── grub
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── i386-pc
│   └── locale
└── lost+found
```

**This is how you can check the type of boot:**

```
sudo efibootmgr
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
```

...than BIOS booting.

Comment: Obviously you use bios boot, not efi boot, therefor you don't have an ESP and there are no efi-files in bios boot. Don't try to find them, they do not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can check that:                                                                                                   `sudo efibootmgr
EFI variables are not supported on this system.`